# CakePHP 3.x single association based on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations

I have a table "InvoiceRows" **belonging to** "Products" (and many more associations). The goal was to have a versioned database, so therefore "InvoiceRows" has 2 "Products"-related fields: `InvoiceRows`.`product_id` and `InvoiceRows`.`product_revision`.

My initial idea was to have 2 tables for "Products": `Products` (current products) and `products_old` (older versions of products). This is working perfectly: as soon as a product is changed, the old version is copied to `ProductsOld` and the field `Products`.`revision` is incremented.
To make the final association, firstly a SELECT will be executed on `Products`, and if it returns nothing, the same SELECT will be executed on `ProductsOld`.

---

In other words:

I want to accomplish: `InvoiceRows` belongsTo `Products` (existing of `Products` and `ProductsOld`):

1. Check `Products` for the latest product, as it will most often be the required product
2. If found, we're ready. If not, check `ProductsOld` for an older version of the product.
3. If found, we're ready.

---

However, I can't seem to get this association appropiatly setup in the xxxTable.php files. I would like to accomplish this by only changing the InvoiceRows->belongsTo(...); and Products->hasMany(...); function configurations.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp's associations are essentially a wrapper for a SQL's `JOIN` clause. Your concept regarding *if not found, then..* does not translate well (if it all) to SQL programming. Thus, I do not think you will find a solution that follows the exact logic you described.

A couple alternative "solutions":

Have your `InvoiceRow` belongTo both `Product` and `ProductsOld` - but you will need to have two different relations. When you query the database, both tables are searched simultaneously. You will need code to deal with the two scenarios:

- Value from `Products`, and not `ProductsOld`
- Value from `ProductsOld`, and not `Products`

Another solution (*this was a capability of Cakephp v2, unsure of v3*), is to create a SQL view which `UNION`'s `Products` and `ProductsOld`, base a model on that view and use that relation for these purposes.